# How does Python Queue know it will be empty?

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I would like to understand how a queue knows that it wont receive any new items. In the following example the queue will indefintely wait when the `tputter` thread is not started (I assume because nothing was put to it so far). If the `tputter` is started it waits between 'puts' until something new is there and as soon as everything is finished it stops. But how does the `tgetter` know whether something new will end up in the queue or not?

```
import threading
import queue
import time

q = queue.Queue()

def getter():
    for i in range(5):
        print('worker:', q.get())
        time.sleep(2)


def putter():
    for i in range(5):
        print('putter: ', i)
        q.put(i)
        time.sleep(3)

tgetter = threading.Thread(target=getter)
tgetter.start()
tputter = threading.Thread(target=putter)
#tputter.start()
```

Comment: What do you mean? `getter` waits for things to be polled from the queue, it doesn't "know" that things will be put into the queue such that it will eventually stop waiting; it waits because that's what it is programmed to do.

Comment: If you are asking why `tgetter` ends at the same time as `tputter`, it's simply because both of them are programmed to loop five times (`for i in range(5):`), if `tgetter` were in an infinite loop (`while True:`) it would still hang after `tputter` is done.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm not sure if my answer is actually addressing the question. The first sentence seems very straightforward: "I would like to understand how a queue knows that it wont receive any new items", but what follows is a little bit confusing.

Comment: thanks guys! i see how my idea is majorly flawed, so the issue seems more monday-related than code-related. But @dano already answered the follow up question on how to stop a getter, so we have that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use the "poison pill" pattern. Basically, the producer and consumer agree on a special "poison pill" object that the producer can load into the queue, which will indicate that no more items are going to be sent, and the consumer can shut down.

So, in your example, it'd look like this:

```
import threading
import queue
import time

q = queue.Queue()
END = object()

def getter():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item == END:
           break
        print('worker:', item)
        time.sleep(2)


def putter():
    for i in range(5):
        print('putter: ', i)
        q.put(i)
        time.sleep(3)
    q.put(END)

tgetter = threading.Thread(target=getter)
tgetter.start()
tputter = threading.Thread(target=putter)
#tputter.start()
```

This is a little contrived, since the producer is hard-coded to always send five items, so you have to imagine that the consumer doesn't know ahead of time how many items the producer will send.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wanted the "correct" solution for the problem of an indeterminate number of exchanges or just to understand the behavior of the posted code... In any case, what you posted is indeed a good solution, but just as a comment, if you want to avoid aliasing between an actual message and the termination signal (e.g. if `-1` is a valid value), you can do `END = object()` and check for `if item is END:` instead.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I just left a comment above expressing that same uncertainty about what the OP is looking for. And yes, I agree that using `object()` is better and will update my answer to use that instead.